# Instantiate AWS cred env vars on the CLI from AWS Identity Center

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash

I've moved to using AWS Identity Center for creds.
I follow the instructions and have a way to set the profile in the linux/mac CLI via a browser.  I can then instantiate traditional AWS creds for third party pipelines by copy/pasting them from the browser  onto the CLI.

Is there a way to do this workflow entirely from the CLI?  Using an admin test setup, I still get not authorized from `aws sts ... --profile my_profile`.

Ideally, I'd alias the running of a small bash script which runs the `aws sso login` and then harvests the creds from the API, but other than a bit of python/bash, I'm no dev, so a bit stumped as to how to do this effectively.